# Where Does the Talmud Teach Not to Learn Halacha From Observation of Teachers?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, rabbis, halacha-theory

Back when I was learning Daf Yomi, I ran into an interesting lesson I'm finding difficult to find again.  It was a teaching that one should learn halacha from your rebbe's teachings and not through the observation of pious people.  The reason, as I recall, was that the observation can be misleading.  Observing the tzaddik may not take into account that he is properly relying on a heter, or perhaps that he is relying on a chumra.  Therefore, one should only learn the halacha from the lectures.  I can recall this lesson vividly, but I can't remember where I learned it.  I thought it might be in Moed Kattan, but I haven't found it there in my review.  Can anyone help?  I need the source for an article I'm working on.  Thanks.

Comment: That's interesting, because many times we find a concern that the students might see some rabbis acting some way and set the halachah that way forever, e.g. [Brachos 11a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=11&format=pdf), [Pesachim 100a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=100&format=pdf)

Comment: @ba And see [Shabbos 21a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=21&format=text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mesechta Bava Basra 130:](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9585&st=&pgnum=264&hilite=) is the source

Comment: And it says....?

Comment: Perfect.  I hadn't even thought to look there.  Now that I have, I see my notes on the page.  In English (per Art Scroll), the text says "The Rabbis taught in a Baraisa: one may not derive practical halacha from [an observation made by sages in the course of their] study or from [a ruling issued by sages in] a case [that came before them] unless they say to one: 'Halacha l'maisa' [this is the halacha to be followed in practice]."